# Latest version of VirtualBox won't open on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualbox

I have the latest version of Virtual Box. When I try opening it, it doesn't open. To debug, I opened task manager to see that it opens for a sec, then closes.

I am running a **Windows 10 Pro** 64-bit **AMD A8-6410** processer with **AMD Radeon R5 graphics** and **12GB of RAM.**

What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: I've seen lots of mention in the past that VirtualBox and Hyper-V can't run at the same time. So in Windows / Control Panel / Programs / Turn Features On and Off, make sure Hyper-V is not checked.

Comment: And while I believe you that you downloaded the latest version, please state what that version is (from VirtualBox / About).  Likewise, exact version number of Windows 10 Pro (Settings / System / About / Version).  Maybe an issue with the latest Windows 10 update, and some corresponding update will be needed for VirtualBox (so you might be stuck until that is updated)?

Comment: I solved it. Thanks for your concern. You may post your answer as an answer as it might be useful for future readers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was getting the VirtualBox given by Genymotion; which is **at this time outdated**  (Given 5.0.2, latest is **5.1.8**).

Getting the latest version fixed it.